# Load telegram chat history with Watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing my first webscraper in rails and I need to retrieve the chat history from a group I am a part of in Telegram.

I know telegram is written in React so I couldn't use mechanize so I decided to try Watir for now. I am able to have Watir login and see the group chats, but only the last 100 or so messages display unless you scroll up to display more of the history. So when I use

`browser.element(class: "im_history_messages_peer").text.strip`

I only get the most recent messages. I see that Telegram has an API, but I am not sure how to use it to log in to my account and get a day's worth of chat histories from my groups. Is Watir a viable option for this kind of scraping job?

Comment: You should definitely use the API if possible, it will be a more long-term solution. Although there are ways to trigger the infinite scroll with an automated browser.

Comment: I'm still learning, and have only ever used ruby gems when dealing with API's. I wasn't able to figure out how to setup the TG api within a rails app when I was reading their docs. I created an app, but I am not sure where to send each query to auth each user.

Comment: The API looks pretty straightforward. Here's the method you'll need: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory

Comment: I'm unsure of how to call the methods. Are there endpoints that I can send params to?

Comment: Seems like it, the documentation specifies which parameters does the endpoint support, you just have to authenticate first.

Comment: With the API I would have to be a super user for the group I am trying to scrape the history from. I am just a normal user. I am considering creating a background worker that saves incoming messages using Watir. I need 24 hours worth of a chat history, so I could just wait a day with it running.